# AWS IoT Mosquitto Certificate Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto, aws-iot

I'm running into a really frustrating error with trying to bridge mosquitto to the AWS IoT MQTT system.  I set it up following this guide:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-bridge-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-aws-iot/

Which at first seemed to work.  I was able to see messages in he AWS IoT console when I subscribed to it.  Then I restarted mosquitto and I'm just getting this error over and over again:

```
1529722121: OpenSSL Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
1529722121: Socket error on client local.bridgeawsiot, disconnecting.
1529722151: Bridge local.bridgeawsiot doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic localgateway_to_awsiot
1529722151: Bridge local.bridgeawsiot doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic both_directions
1529722151: Connecting bridge awsiot (a10cxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8883)
1529722182: Connecting bridge awsiot (a10cxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8883)
```

I've verified multiple times that the certificates that I'm using are the correct ones, I've also checked that the Thing has a policy attached to it and that the certificates are activated.  I made sure that the rootCA.pem file is the one issued from Verisign.  I'm at a loss as to why the broker is not working.  The host OS is Ubuntu 18.04 running the bundled version of mosquitto.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was.  I was using the CLI to retrieve my IoT endpoint and my default region was set to us-west-2.  The certificates that I created are in us-east-1.